# UIButton with custom background loses title

Tags: uibutton

I was trying to create a custom button, but after setting the image, I noticed that the title disappears, it think this is because I add an image to the button, which overlaps the title.

```
UIImage *pickerBg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_picker.png"];
UIImage *pickerBg_highlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_picker_highlighted.png"];

[projectBtn setImage:pickerBg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[projectBtn setImage:pickerBg_highlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Is there another way on how to do this?

Comment: add your title after you setting the image to the button.That is after [projectBtn setImage:pickerBg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[projectBtn setImage:pickerBg_highlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

Comment: I've already tried that, but didn't seem to help: [projectBtn setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a UILabel with the title you need, then add it as a subview to your UIButton.

Comment: That does indeed work, it was my idea at first too, but I was hoping there was an easier solution.

Comment: It changes, it's a button that triggers a UIPicker, so it would change depending on what's selected in the picker

Answer (score 4):

Use setBackgroundImage, not setImage

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImage *pickerBg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_picker.png"];
UIImage *pickerBg_highlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_picker_highlighted.png"];
[projectBtn setBackgroundImage:pickerBg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[projectBtn setBackgroundImage:pickerBg_highlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[projectBtn setTitle:@"aTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Use this to set image with title.

Answer (score 0):

when you create a UIButton, use setImage to set ButtonImage will change title's position,the titleText and the image are at At the same level,the titleText  in behind of image,so you can setBackImage, the image will behind the titleText,but ,the image will tension as the button.